# Mysterious "value computed is not used" warnings on __atomic_exchange_n

Tags: c, gcc, atomic, gcc4.9, reentrancy

I developed a reentrant function based on the atomic builtins of the gcc. Unfortunately, I get mysterious warnings about "computed but not used" values:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall ss.c
ss.c: In function ‘ss_wrapper’:
ss.c:87:3: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   __atomic_exchange_n(&ss_top, hit, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
   ^
ss.c:91:5: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
     __atomic_exchange_n(&ss_top, bkp->next, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST); // release the lock, find out if there is new element
     ^
```

This is my function:

```
static void ss_wrapper(int signum, siginfo_t* siginfo, void *ucontext) {
  // currently top element on the signal stack
  static struct ss_hit* ss_top = NULL;


  struct ss_hit* hit = ss_newhit(signum, siginfo, (ucontext_t*)ucontext);
  struct ss_hit* bkp;

  again:

  bkp = hit;
  __atomic_exchange_n(&ss_top, hit, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
  if (!hit) { // we got the lock, we are the master
    ss_fire(bkp);

    // release the lock, find out if there is new element
    __atomic_exchange_n(&ss_top, bkp->next, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (bkp->next) { // there IS

      hit = bkp;
      free(bkp);
      goto again;

    } else
      free(bkp);
  } else { // we didn't got the lock, but we got the top in hit
    __atomic_store(&hit->next, &bkp, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
  }
}
```

Why does it happen? `__atomic_exchange_n` shouldn't compute anything, it only swaps the content of two variables.

Comment: The whole source file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HorvathAkosPeter/pipenet/master/staging/ss.c).

Comment: You should not use the atomic-builtins directly, but use C11 `stdatomic.h`. Why make your code depend on a compiler without actual need.

Comment: @Olaf I tried to use the possible lowest level, because of the lack of trust. But now that my code produces good asm, there is no more reason to not use the standard-compliant way, and this is what I will do.

Comment: "lack of trust"... Well, as this is a header-only feature, you can easily verify this. So you verify all assember your compiler generates? What if the assembler is mapped to the wrong machine-codes? Where do you stop?

Comment: @Olaf Not all, only which does hardware-near things, for example atomic operations. Verify the asm of an atomic instruction is a very simple thing, and in my previous tries I've found multiple times that the atomic builtins produced suspicious code (f.e. if it reads the variable from the stack, does the swap in regs, and puts it back, it is already _not_ atomic). Another reason was that I wanted to see, how gcc does this.

Comment: Depends on the memory order you specify and the architecture. Some architecture like ARM use a lock-free, non-blocking restart mechanism where you **do** use such operations. Not sure about x86.

Comment: @Olaf Another reason was that I simply didn't found the C11 stdatomic.h, only c++ things which I also didn't trust. Now I found, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only swaps the content of two variables

No, it does not.  It swaps the content of one variable with the content of a register.  The second variable is never changed.  (Even without consulting the documentation, this is apparent from the different convention for passing the two parameters -- the memory address which is atomically exchanged is passed as a pointer, the other value is copied, not accessed in place)

As a result of this misunderstanding, your logic is broken.  You meant to do:

```
hit = __atomic_exchange_n(&ss_top, hit, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
if (!hit) { // we got the lock, we are the master
```

which writes the new values of the register back into the second variable.  The accesses to `hit` are non-atomic, but that's ok because it is a local variable, not shared with any other thread.

**Do not just throw away the return value, if you do, you will never enter the branch for "we are the master"**

Comment: You have right, this is really the only way to make the asm perfect... maybe I misunderstood the gcc builtin docs, maybe not. :-(

Answer (score -1):

@Olaf answered my question in a comment: although declare a dummy variable with `__attribute__((unused))` and giving him the return values avoids the warnings, but there is also a much simpler way to do that: casting the functions to `(void)`, so:

```
(void)__atomic_exchange_n(...);
```

*Extension: although this solution also eliminates the warning, it still doesn't use the `__atomic_exchange_n` gcc builtin correctly (although sometimes it compiled correct code). The accepted answer solves finally the problem.*

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all.  Yes, it shows how to discard the result of the expression, but reading the entire function, it is clear that the result is needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt You have right, this is really the only way to make the asm perfect... maybe I misunderstood the gcc builtin docs, maybe not. :-(